# what is right way to multiple sorting in mysql

Tags: mysql

how i can use multiple sorting in mysql

```
ORDER BY PARAM1 , PARAM2
```

or

```
ORDER BY PARAM1 AND PARAM2 AND PARAM3 DESC
```

what is write way to sorting in mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [**Mysql Select Syntax**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) you can see that that the correct syntax for using `ORDER BY` is:

```
[ORDER BY {col_name | expr | position}
[ASC | DESC], ...]
            ^
comma separated
```

So your first option is correct.

Answer (score 1):

The first one is correct.

Answer (score 0):

ORDER BY field1, field2, ...